# converting data from text to CSV and modifying it in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, text

There is a data in my text file. It is a list of IP addresses in column, I want to convert it into csv file and with that also i want to create 3 more columns and put the same data that is present in the first column
so far have created this

```
$output_file= "D:\output.csv"
```

#the headers i have given below

```
Set-Content D:\output.csv 'record,stream,library,thumbnail'
$input_file= "D:\input1.txt"
$lines = Get-Content $input_file
foreach ($line in $lines) {
  Add-Content -Path $output_file -Value "$line, $line, $line, $line"
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how can I Put the same data from column1 in other 3 columns?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Why not go the **object** way?

```
$output_file = "D:\output.csv"
$input_file  = "D:\input1.txt"
Get-Content -Path $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    # output an object
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        record    = $_
        stream    = $_
        library   = $_
        thumbnail = $_
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```